# Is 9/1 an improper fraction?

Tags: terminology, education, fractions

My son took a test in school. The teacher told them that they did not need to simplify improper fractions in their answers.

On one question, for example, the answer of 28/3 was marked as correct. But when's son correctly answered 9/1 to one question and 10/1 to another, the teacher marked both wrong. The teacher explained that 9/1 and 10/1 are not improper fractions.

The textbook provides an example of 9/9 as an improper fraction, but nothing where the denominator is 1. Frankly, I think this sort of nonsense makes students hate math and school. Lots of hard work, follow instructions, and the teacher flunks you anyway.

Comment: I suspect the teacher wanted $9$ instead of $9/1$. At any rate, tell your kid he's done good. I agree with you, it is a simple detail kids should not be forced to think is wrong, but rather, it is just an unnecessary notation.

Comment: "Improper fraction" is a nonsense phrase taught in grade school; it's not a real mathematical term. Googling to find out what it means, though, gets me that it refers to a rational number being written $p/q$, where $p>q$; what they want students to do is write it as $a+b/c$, where $a$ is an integer and $b/c$ is a fraction with $b<c$. For example, $8/3$ is an 'improper' fraction, and should be 'simplified' as $2+2/3$. At the same time, though, this just teaches students bad practice, as just a few years later they'll be writing all fractions in this 'improper' form!

Comment: @Mike almost—students are *actually* taught to write $8/3$ as $2\frac{1}{3}$, i.e. to omit the plus sign. This is IMO disastrously bad notation and the "proper" v. "improper" nomenclature is inappropriate and it's just a bad practice all around.

Comment: two and one third ??

Comment: @Mike: *Improper fraction* is not a nonsense phrase: it has a perfectly clear meaning. Moreover, the distinction is important in some contexts (e.g., in another Euclidean domain, in partial fraction decomposition). You should also note that this teacher was quite reasonably **not** insisting that students rewrite improper fractions as mixed numbers (integer plus proper fraction), so your complaint is comment is not relevant to the Marshall’s (quite reasonable) complaint.

Comment: @crf: Bad practice would be failing to teach students to understand a notation that is in common use, and the fact is that mixed notation **is** in common use. It would also be bad practice not to teach students how to convert it into the mathematically more useful notation. However, neither point is actually at issue here.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I see your point; I'd never seen use of the term 'improper fraction' outside of grade school, and mixed numbers outside of drafting. I'll leave the comment up for posterity. I stand by the complaint that teachers shouldn't punish for writing fractions as $p/q$ only for high school math teachers to demand it later; this usually isn't framed as teaching them to learn mixed fraction notation, but rather just 'how to write fractions', which they're then told later is wrong.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott fair, but in my experience working with students at the high school level, they don't necessarily see that $2\frac{1}{3}$ is the same as $2+\frac{1}{3}$. Then you end up with kids mechanically, mindlessly "converting" improper fractions to proper fractions, adding, and then reconverting back into proper fractions in order to evaluate, say, $2\frac{1}{3}+3\frac{2}{3}$, instead of recognizing that they may as well just go $2+3+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{3}$. This is all very much beside the main point though I guess.

Comment: Since your son's class considers the whole number `9/9`, whose fractional form's numerator is not less than its denominator, an improper fraction, then it seems inconsistent to claim that `9/1` is not also an improper fraction.

Answer (score 2):

Techniccaly 9/1 is an improper fraction since the denominator is less than the numerator. But the teacher wants to avoid the students spending time on converting an improper fraction into a mixed number, yet the teacher expects the students to wrote 9/1 as 9 as it is "obvious". I think that the teacher should point this out very clear before the test takes place what is to be expected here. (Or maybe he did, we don't know) Anyway, to mark it wrong altogether is overkill and certainly a reason why a kid may not like math anymore. I would say, either simply an improper fraction into a mixed number at all times, or you don't.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is very appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The definition of "improper fraction" that your son would have probably been given is something like "an improper fraction is a number of the form $\frac{p}{q}$ where $p$ and $q$ are both whole numbers and $p\geq q$". I find it very doubtful that your son's teacher, or the textbook, would have included anything which excludes $q=1$, so unless the teacher said that this special case was to be excluded from the definition, $9/1$ is an improper fraction. If it's not an improper fraction, then *what is it*? It's certainly not a a proper fraction, nor is it a mixed fraction.

"Simplifying" an improper fraction in this context is writing it as a "mixed" fraction, which is a number with an integer part and a fractional part. In the case of $9/1$, the integer part is $9$ and the fractional part is $0$, so to write $\frac{9}{1}=9$ is indeed "simplifying an improper fraction", and I understand why your son would have left his answer like that.

The teacher is probably trying to make sure that students understand that $\frac{9}{1}$ is in fact "obviously" equal to $9$. That's a noble goal I guess, but according to the instructions as you've relayed them, $\frac{9}{1}$ is certainly a correct response.